# Identity 2.0 with integer keys: Why User.IsInRole always returns false?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using Identity 2.0, I have modified to use integer as primary key following
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

It works great except when from the controller, I call:

```
User.IsUserInRole("admin");
```

It always returns false. I have checked the underlying table and data is fine.

However, if I do:

```
var t = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
bool ok = t.IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(), "admin");
```

then it works fine. It seems that the problem is only in `Controller.User`

Also, attributes do not work, for example `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]`

Somebody have had the same problem?

UPDATE:

It is nothing related with the controller, `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` has the same problem:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("admin");
```

UPDATE 2:

It seems that the problem is in the AspNetUserRoles table. Identity has added a new column, a foreign key to my extended user table. It seems redundant to me because there is UserId column. The problem is all values of this column are NULL. I think if I am able to understand how to redirect to UserId, everything will work fine.

Comment: [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] and User.IsInRole checking the cookie which created during the login. There should be something wrong the way you set authentication cookie which hasn't included role information of the user.

Comment: DSR, however the following code works fine:
var t = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
bool ok = t.IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(), "admin");

Comment: Yes, that's right, because you accessing the database directly using that code. [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] and User.IsInRole does not access database instead getting information from authentication cookie. Post your owin start up code where you set up your authentication cookies. Follow these video tutorials http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857806/extending-identityuserrole-in-identity-2-0/25857923#25857923

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Role claim when user signs in

Answer (score 0):

I solved it: The problem was I created a class derived from IdentityUser, additionally I enabled Table per Type (TPT) by mistake, adding the table name. Identity 2.0 added a third column in AspNetUserRoles pointing to this new type, and since it was null, there were not roles.
Now, I use Table Per Hierarchy (TPH) and everything works fine.